# How to remove an empty object from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript Array of Objects, on a button click I push an object into the array and then use that as a datasource for a grid. The issue I am facing is that initially the first object in the array is all blank values and when I load the grid I have a blank row because of the empty object... How do I remove that empty object from the array before I load the grid?

Here is the array

```
var gridData = {
    step3GridData: [{ Description: "", Color: "", SqSiding: "" }]
};
```

and on a button click I am pushing a new object to the array

```
gridData.step3GridData.push({ Description: $("#InfoInsul").text(), Color: $("#ddGetInsulationMaterialColor").val(), SqSiding: $("#ddInsulationSquares").val() });

LoadStep3(gridData.step3GridData);
```

As mentioned, I need to remove that empty object before I bind the load with the array. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just don't push the new object unless it's is filled!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, won't the object always be filled since there is an empty object and returns empty strings?

Comment: I meant its properties! Wait I'll post an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialize your array like this:

```
var gridData = {
    step3GridData: [] // empty array
};
```

Then when you are pushing a new object, check if the inputs are filled like this:

```
var desc = $("#InfoInsul").text();             // this seems unnecessary as this is not left to the user to fill (if I'm assuming right then don't check if this is empty)
var col = $("#ddGetInsulationMaterialColor").val();
var sqs = $("#ddInsulationSquares").val();
if(desc.length && col.length && sqs.length) { // if desc is not empty and col is not empty and sqs not empty then add an object
    gridData.step3GridData.push({ Description: desc, Color: col, SqSiding:  });
}
```

Now if the user left something empty, the object won't get pushed, thus there will be no empty objects. You can make use of `else` to alert a message saying that the user left some input blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).  If you are certain it is always the first item in the array, you can do:

```
if (gridData.length && Object.keys(gridData[0]).length === 0) {
  gridData.splice(0, 1);
}
```

If you are not certain about its position, you can traverse the array and remove the first empty object:

```
for (const [idx, obj] of gridData.entries()) {
    if (Object.keys(obj).length) === 0) {
        gridData.splice(idx, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the splice worked and removed the first row, but when I added more objects, it continued to remove the first object, so my grid would always only show the new object

Comment: Hmm - you'll probably want to add a check before calling `splice`;  I'll update my answer